# How can I use basic Safari shortcuts in Google Docs?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, shortcut, google-docs

With tab overview (⌘ + ⇧ + ), show sidebar (⌘ + ⇧ + L), preferences (⌘ + ,) (this triggers subscript), show history (⌘ + Y), and many, many more standard Safari shortcuts either being overridden, disabled, or used in different ways by Google’s app suite, it makes it hard for me to get anything done in Docs/Slides/Etc. Is there a way to get around Google’s incompatible shortcut mappings? I am pretty sure this is designed to get me to switch to Chrome, but I that’s not my browser of choice. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think there’s a fix for you. Apple has designed their shortcuts to be harmonious with a long history of pre-existing app and system key commands that go back decades.

Google has very intentionally designed their app to ignore that history and for reasons I am sure they considered in committee and likely many times with many people. The end result of that work is they have designed their tool to be harmonious with different legacy and existing shortcuts (perhaps on windows, perhaps just they made their thing to stand alone) and collide head on with Apple’s set of shortcuts.

It will be very painful to require your brain and slightly less painful fe the suite settings to free up the ones you need on a trial and error basis (or systematically considering all the settings and keeping it tuned up over time as the app makes changes)

- https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9298571?hl=en

Comment: That’s what I figured. For me the solution is to simply pivot more often to different software, not adopt Chrome and what I consider a sub par workflow with harder to press shortcuts, and tell everyone about what I think about Google’s interaction design decisions. ;) 

At least I was able to make my Magic Mouse work with Slides which haphazardly used to skip back and forth through pages when touching it making it seem like the hardware was broken. That’s in: Tools → Preferences → General → Do not change slide focus on scroll

Comment: I agree @user511035 - I ruthlessly discard software that doesn't work the way my brain does or goes too far against patterns I've cultivated (or just happen to have formed over time).